# Terminal doesen't respond

Tags: virtualbox, gnome-terminal

**I can't use the Ubuntu terminal. I try to open it, he is loading and after a little time he just auto-close itself. Do someone know what's the problem and how to solve it? I will be grateful... **

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing a different Terminal application from the Software Store, there are many to choose from.

Alternatively, you can `ssh` or `telnet` into your Ubuntu machine to get at the command line that way and figure out what's wrong. From here you can also install different Terminal applications from the command line. For example, to install Gnome Console: `sudo apt install gnome-console`.

Comment: Hello friend! I rlly thought about installing another terminal aplication but I was wondering if he can be similar with the original terminal, and I will document myself in connection with ssh and telnet, I don't know much about them because I'm new into this kind of things. Thank you so much for your response Anthony, I have a big respect for you!